# Yum Lock on AWS Linux t2.micro instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, yum

I am continuing to receive a yum lock error each time I attempt to run yum update -y on an AWS Linux t2 micro. I have attempted to kill the process PID # associated with the yum update -y process but have not been able to resolve the lock.

I have terminated and created a new AWS Linux t2 micro, and obtain the same error with the new instance.

Has anyone encountered this error and how did you resolve it?

Thank you for any guidance/help.

This is the message I am receiving when attempting to run yum list:

Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
The other application is: yum
Memory :  35 M RSS (335 MB VSZ)
Started: Wed Oct 20 11:56:55 2021 - 03:27 ago
State  : Sleeping, pid: 3162

I had never previously encountered this error when launching AWS EC2 instances.

I have typically run bootstrap scripts that call yum to install apache and when I launch multiple instances with this bootstrap script, this causes this error.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure the other process is killed you can remove (as root) file
`/var/run/yum.pid`
which is the file yum command complain